# Dojo dgrid: how style a single row?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I want to style a single row and avoid defining formatters for each cell of my row. Is there an equivalent of the onStyleRow event for the new [Dojo dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/) widget?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on what I can understand, it seems the [onStyleRow](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/pull/561) was abused. This [post](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/236) shows a possible solution if it meets your needs.

Comment: Yes, this comment: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/236#issuecomment-11508012 but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Dojo 1.9

Comment: OK got it, the code can't be added to the definition of my Dgrid, but in a context, like in a controller, where I actually *create* (with new keyword) my grid.

Comment: Nice job! Could you add your solution to your question for others with similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with two distinct solutions:

1. In the controller using the dgrid, based on the workaround given at https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/236#issuecomment-11508012

   ```
       aspect.after(myDgrid, "renderRow", function(row, args) {
           var data = args[0];
           if (data.unread) {
               domClass.add(row, "unread");
           }
           return row;
       });
   ```
2. In my own dgrid definition, but without "use strict" - otherwise this won't work and you'll get this error: `TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`:

   ```
   return declare("com.my.myDgrid", [ Grid, ... ], {
       columns : [ {
           ...
       } ],

       renderRow : function() {
           var row = this.inherited(arguments);
           var data = arguments[0];
           if (data.unread) {
               domClass.add(row, "unread");
           }
           return row;
       }
   });
   ```

The styling is done via this simple CSS rule:

```
    #myDgridId .unread td {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```